# Java WatchService watches not terminated

Tags: java, eclipse, watchservice

I'm working on an application that uses the Java watchservice (Java 8) under Linux Mint.  One interesting problem I am encountering is running out of inotify watches.

I'm developing under Eclipse and the behavior is as follows:

When the app starts, it recurses a directory structure, putting a watch on each directory found.  The current test case uses 13,660 paths.  My maximum is set to 16384.

If I stop and restart the app several (20+ times), it seems to function normally.  Eventually, however, I will get a cascade of system errors indicating the maximum number of watches has been reached.  However, if I restart Eclipse, the issue goes away.

Obviously, the Watch Service isn't releasing all of it's resources, but of the 13,660 watches it acquires, only a few (I'm guessing less than a hundred) are retained.  It appears they aren't released unless I shut down Eclipse's Java instance and restart it.

To address this, I've ensured the watch service's close method is called when the application shuts down and the watch service task is cancelled.

The only other thing that I'm doing differently is I'm running two separate watch services for two different purposes.  I'm told that you shouldn't need to run more than one, and perhaps this is the problem, but I'd rather not run one watch service if I can help it.

That said, are there any thoughts or suggestions on how I might be able to determine the cause of this bug?

---

Apologies for the massive code posting.  This is my implementation of the WatchService class.

A few notes:

The pathFinder runs in a separate thread and is just a file visitor - walking the directory tree and returning paths to all dirs / files found.

Register is called only when changes are posted to the pathsChanged property (from the pathFinder's onSucceeded callback).

The pathsChanged property is always updated by a setAll() call.  It only posts the latest changes and is not meant to be cumulative.  Beyond the watchservice, other classes listen to these properties and respond accordingly.

```
public final class LocalWatchService extends BaseTask {

private final static String TAG  = "LocalWatchService";
//watch service task
private WatchService watcher;

//path finding task and associated executor
private LocalPathFinder finder;

//root path where the watch service begins 
private final Path mRootPath;

private final ExecutorService pathFinderExecutor = 
                                    createExecutor ("pathFinder", false);

//class hash map which keys watched paths to generated watch keys
private final Map<WatchKey, Path> keys = new HashMap<WatchKey, Path>();

//reference to model property of watched paths.
private final SimpleListProperty <SyncPath> mChangedPaths = 
        new SimpleListProperty <SyncPath> 
                            (FXCollections.<SyncPath> observableArrayList());

public LocalWatchService (String rootPath) {

    super ();

    mRootPath = Paths.get(rootPath);

    //create the watch service
    try {
        this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setOnCancelled(new EventHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event arg0) {
            pathFinderExecutor.shutdown();
        }
    });

    mChangedPaths.addListener(new ListChangeListener <SyncPath> (){

        @Override
        public void onChanged( 
            javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends SyncPath> 
                            arg0) {

                for (SyncPath path: arg0.getList()) {

                    //call register only when a directory is found
                    if (path.getFile() == null) {
                        try {
                            register (path.getPath());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
};

public SimpleListProperty<SyncPath> changedPaths() { return mChangedPaths; }

public void initializeWatchPaths() {

    ArrayList <Path> paths = new ArrayList <Path> ();

    //create a DirectoryStream filter that finds only directories
    //and symlinks

    DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> filter = 
        new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {

            public boolean accept(Path file) throws IOException {

                return (Files.isDirectory(file) || 
                        Files.isSymbolicLink(file));
            }
        };

    //apply the filter to a directory stream opened on the root path
    //and save everything returned.
    paths.addAll(utils.getFiles(mRootPath, filter));

    runPathFinder (paths);
}

private void runPathFinder (ArrayList <Path> paths) {

    //need to add blocking code / mechanism in case a path finder is 
    //currently running (rare case)

    finder = new LocalPathFinder();
    finder.setPaths (paths);

    //callbacks on successful completion of pathfinder

    EventHandler <WorkerStateEvent> eh = 
        new EventHandler <WorkerStateEvent> () {

            ArrayList <SyncPath> paths = new ArrayList <SyncPath>();

            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent arg0) {
                    for (Path p: finder.getPaths()) {
                        paths.add(
                            new SyncPath(mRootPath, p, SyncType.SYNC_NONE));
                    }

                addPaths(paths);
            }

        };

    finder.setOnSucceeded(eh);

    pathFinderExecutor.execute (finder);        
}

private void addPath(Path path, SyncType syncType) {
    mChangedPaths.setAll(new SyncPath(mRootPath, path, syncType));
}

private void addPaths(ArrayList<SyncPath> paths) {
    mChangedPaths.setAll(paths);
}

/**
 * Register the given directory with the WatchService
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
public final void register(Path dir) 
                                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    //register the key with the watch service
    WatchKey key = 
        dir.register (watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);


    if (!keys.isEmpty()) {

        Path prev = keys.get(key);

        if (prev == null) {
            //This is a new key
        }
        else if (!dir.equals(prev)) {
            //This is an update
        }
    }

    keys.put(key, dir);
}

private void processWatchEvent (WatchKey key, Path dir) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {

        WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();        

        // TBD - provide example of how OVERFLOW event is handled
        if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
            System.out.println ("Overflow encountered");
        }

        WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>)event;
        Path target = dir.resolve(ev.context());

        if (kind == ENTRY_DELETE) {

            ArrayList <Path> finderList = new ArrayList <Path> ();

            if (Files.isDirectory(target)) {
                //directory deletion is not implemented apart from
                //file deletion
            }
            else
                addPath (target, SyncType.SYNC_DELETE);

        } else if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE) {

            /*
             * Added paths are passed to the pathfinder service for
             * subdirectory discovery.  Path and subpaths are then added
             * to the AddedPaths property via an event listener on
             * service's onSucceeded() event.
             * 
             * Added files are added directly to the AddedPaths property
             */

            ArrayList <Path> finderList = new ArrayList <Path> ();

            if (Files.isDirectory(target)) {
                finderList.add (target);
                runPathFinder (finderList);
            }
            //add files directly to the addedPaths property
            else {

                //a newly created file may not be immediately readable
                if (Files.isReadable(target)) {
                        addPath (target, SyncType.SYNC_CREATE);
                }
                else
                    System.err.println ("File " + target + " cannot be read");
            }

        } else if (kind == ENTRY_MODIFY) {
            System.out.println ("File modified: " + target.toString());
        }
        boolean valid = key.reset();

        if (!valid)
            break;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<T> WatchEvent<T> cast(WatchEvent<?> event) {
    return (WatchEvent<T>)event;
}

@Override
protected Void call () throws IOException, InterruptedException {

boolean interrupted = false;

register (mRootPath);
initializeWatchPaths();

try {
    // enter watch cycle
    while (!interrupted) {

         //watch for a key change.  Thread blocks until a change occurs
        WatchKey key = null;
        interrupted = isCancelled();

         //thread blocks until a key change occurs 
         // (whether a new path is processed by finder or a watched item changes otherwise)

        try {
            key = watcher.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            interrupted = true;
            try {
                watcher.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            // fall through and retry
        }

        Path dir = keys.get (key);

        if (dir == null) {
           System.out.println ("Null directory key encountered.");
            continue;
        }

        //process key change once it occurs
        processWatchEvent(key, dir);

        // reset key and remove from set if directory no longer accessible
        if (!key.reset()) {

            keys.remove(key);

            // all directories are inaccessible
            if (keys.isEmpty())
                break;
        }
    }
} finally {
    if (interrupted)
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
    keys.clear();
    watcher.close();
    return null;
};
```

}

Comment: Some code would be appreciated -- how you pick up events etc

Comment: Posted.  It's not pretty.  Java's not quite my thing yet - haven't quite got the hang of keeping it looking nice...

Comment: Why don't you use a `FileVisitor` and `Files.walkFileTree()` to collect directories? It would be much easier

Comment: I do.  I just wrapped it in a separate class and run it as a separate task.  (see "LocalPathFinder finder;") Unless I misunderstand your comment?